# MDX-Statement - skip level

Tags: mdx

i have the following hierarchy:

group -> country -> place

Some data:

> Blockquote

```
group1 -> france -> place1
group1 -> france -> place2
group1 -> france -> place3
group1 -> italy -> place1
group1 -> italy -> place2
group1 -> spain -> place1
group2 -> france -> place1
group2 -> france -> place2
group2 -> italy-> place1
group3 -> italy-> place1
group3 -> italy-> place2
group3 -> italy-> place3
group3 -> spain-> place1
```

I need a MDX-Statement that is no filter (i work with SAS-OLAP and need to create an authorization on a Dimension):

The authorization should be on level2. The user is in a sas-group "italy" - so 
the user should see all values on level1 - only see "italy" on level2 and on level 3 he should see the childrens of italy.

Can someone please help with the mdx-statement? How is this possible?

Thank you very much

Kind regards

George

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at below sample. I am trying to get parent and all sibilings of the parent of Queensland

SELECT {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0,

{([Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].&[QLD]&[AU]),
([Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].&[QLD]&[AU]).parent.Siblings}
ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]

Result
[image]

To add children to the result too.

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0,

{
([Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].&[QLD]&[AU]), 
([Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].&[QLD]&[AU]).parent.Siblings,
([Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].&[QLD]&[AU]).children
} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Comment: @sorosch i did not use siblings, I used parents.Sibilings which will not return all the members of Level2, It will return all members of Level1. Since sibilings is being called on parents level. So the above query should answer your original question, now if you want to have children also check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much - but with Siblings i get also all other members of level 2 - but i just want on level 2 "italy".

I thought, that in SAS it is not possible to use filters in the authorization of the dimension. However, it is possible. SO i tried the following MDX:

> Blockquote

```
[DIM_NAME].[DIM_NAME_H01].[All GROUPS],
[DIM_NAME].[DIM_NAME_H01].[All GROUPS].Children,

FILTER([DIM_NAME].[DIM_NAME_H01].[All GROUPS].[COUNTRIES].ALLMEMBERS,  
   kupcase([DIM_NAME].[DIM_NAME_H01].CurrentMember.Properties("CAPTION")) =   kupcase("italy"))
```

So i see all members on level 1. --> That´s OK
On Level 2 i just see "italy" merbers. --> That´s OK
But i get no members on Level 3. --> does someone have an idea, how i get also members on level 3? Or are filters not the right approach?

Thank you very much

Kind regards

George

Comment: if you need to clarify something further or add something to question you should do it, by editing the original question. Answers are not for this purpose. Kindly delete this answer. I have addressed your concerns in the comment to my original answer